# Загрузка бота на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

При запуске бота на pythonanywhere выдает ошибку

```
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler
```

При этом, когда запускаю локально, все хорошо.
Использую библиотеку pytelegrambotapi новейшей версии

Comment: Возможно, разные версии на хостинге и локале.

Comment: Дело в том, что на хостинге нужно предварительно установить библиотеку, чтобы она работала. Я так и сделал, однако, он не работает. Нашел еще точно такую же ошибку в компиляторе sublime text, хотя в pycharm работает